# Scrapy Spider scraping wrong data

Tags: parsing, scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

I am building my first spider on scrapy and it aims to scrape the data from a betting website and return the names of the teams playing and the odds. I'm am using a for loop to iterate through a class that encases all of the data needed, but the code is returning the data for the first game 9 times (there are 9 fixtures). What is it I'm doing wrong?

```
    import scrapy

class SportsBetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "odds"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            "https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3"
                ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for post in response.css('li.cardOuterItem_fn8ai8t'):
            yield{
                'Team 1' : post.xpath('//span[@class="size12_fq5j3k2 normal_fgzdi7m caption_f4zed5e"]/text()')[0].get(),
                'Odds 1' : post.xpath('//span[@class="size14_f7opyze medium_f1wf24vo priceTextSize_frw9zm9"]/text()')[0].get(),
                'Team 2' : post.xpath('//span[@class="size12_fq5j3k2 normal_fgzdi7m caption_f4zed5e"]/text()')[1].get(),
                'Odds 2' : post.xpath('//span[@class="size14_f7opyze medium_f1wf24vo priceTextSize_frw9zm9"]/text()')[1].get()
            }
```

And the output is:

> 2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3> (referer: None)
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules/afl/round-3>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 #Only 8 links allowed but same link as before>
>   {'Team 1': 'Richmond', 'Odds 1': '1.36', 'Team 2': 'Hawthorn', 'Odds 2': '3.08'}
>   2020-06-14 20:41:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

It is only showing the scraped data for the first fixture when there are 9 others, how is this fixed?

Comment: This question seems quite dependent on the content of the page you're trying to scrape. Maybe you want to create an example of what the HTML of the page you're scraping looks like and add it to your question so people can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was using absolute xpaths and not relative xpaths. I fixed this by:

```
yield{
            'Team 1' : post.xpath('.//span[@class="size12_fq5j3k2 normal_fgzdi7m caption_f4zed5e"]/text()')[0].get(),
            'Odds 1' : post.xpath('.//span[@class="size14_f7opyze medium_f1wf24vo priceTextSize_frw9zm9"]/text()')[0].get(),
            'Team 2' : post.xpath('.//span[@class="size12_fq5j3k2 normal_fgzdi7m caption_f4zed5e"]/text()')[1].get(),
            'Odds 2' : post.xpath('.//span[@class="size14_f7opyze medium_f1wf24vo priceTextSize_frw9zm9"]/text()')[1].get()
        }
```

making it .// instead of // fixed the issue.